# Escaping characters in a variable for PowerShell's Invoke-Expression

Tags: powershell

I wrote a script to backup a bunch of files by compressing them using 7-Zip. The problem is some of the files contain "&" and "'" (single quote). I tried replacing those out (in the variables below) with "`'" or "``'", but that didn't work either. I guess I am not sure how escaping characters works when used with [Invoke-Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression?view=powershell-6).

Here are the code lines:

```
$exec = "& 'C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe' u -mx5 -tzip -r  '$DestFileZip' '$DestFile'"

Invoke-Expression $exec
```

Answer (score 7):

[This thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/cd08c144-7105-421d-bbce-ab27dcee0fb7/escaping-parameters-for-an-external-program-in-invokeexpression) mentions:

```
$exec = @'
& "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" u -mx5 -tzip -r "$DestFileZip" "$DestFile"
'@

Invoke-Expression $exec
```

> Withing the `@" "@` delimiters, variables and sub-expressions will get expanded, but quotes and other special characters are treated as literals.

Answer (score 1):

Does it work if you ditch Invoke-Expression and execute 7z directly e.g.:

```
& 'C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe' u -mx5 -tzip -r -ppeople123 $DestFileZip $DestFile
```

Although given you're updating the zip with a file, I'm not sure why you're using `-r` - unless $DestFile is really a directory?  Anyway, with 7z 9.20 this works for me - no errors:

```
C:\> $destZip = "foo&bar's.zip"
C:\> $destFile = "foo&bar's.txt"
C:\> & 'C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe' u -mx5 -tzip -ppeople123 $destZip $destFile

7-Zip [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igo Pavlov  2010-11-18    
Scanning

Creating archive foo&bar's.zip

Compressing foo&bar's.txt

Everything is OK
```

Comment: Same thing happens. It doesn't work and gives an error due to the single quote.

Comment: Can you give some specifics on what error you are seeing and what the $destFile value looks like as well as some of the problematic paths.